# SampleResult: Could not convert string 'XXXX' , using default encoding: UTF-8, java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java

When run those code, it throws out errors:

```
public class getRondomNumber extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
    private int index = 0;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getRondomNumber.class);
    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHhhss");
        String tempTime = ft.format(date);

        Random rd = new Random();

        String tempNum = tempTime + String.valueOf(rd.nextInt(1000));
        logger.debug("debug: " + tempNum);
        //logger.error("error: " + tempNum);
        logger.info("info: " + tempNum);

        SampleResult results = new SampleResult();
        results.setSamplerData("： "+ index);
        if(index%2 == 0) {
            results.setSuccessful(true);
        }else {
            results.setSuccessful(false);
        }

        logger.info("This is runned.");

        results.setResponseData("Result： ", tempNum);

        return null;
    }
}
```

When run these codes, it throws out errors like this:
o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Could not convert string using '20180616121200666', using default encoding: UTF-8
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: 20180616121200666
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:341) ~[?:1.8.0_121]

My question is how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go for reference of SampleResult setResponseData:
void    setResponseData(java.lang.String response, java.lang.String encoding).
Change my code to results.setResponseData("Result： "+ tempNum, "UTF-8");. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by doing this:

```
new String(tempNum.getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Why not just use `tempNum` as is?

At any rate, what's happening is that `tempNum.getBytes()` is returning `tempNum` as a series of bytes according to *whatever your local default encoding happens to be*.

Whatever that is, it's clearly not UTF-8.

You can't expect the bytes generated by the output of one string encoding to be consumed properly as the input to a different string encoding.

Comment: Actually, my normal code just like this: 
results.setResponseData("Result： ", tempNum);
It throws out the errors above, so I find way to sovle it.